# How to find out Last Used objects in the system from all libraries except Q*

Tags: ibm-midrange, websphere

Thank you in advance!! but the thing is that I am looking for all the objects in the system except Q* libraries who are used in last 2 years on 31/12/2018. Is there any query can show last used objects around 2 years ago and can omit all objects of Q* no-system libraries please.

Regards, Deepak Mangla

Answer (score 0):

you can use the DSPOBJD command and direct output to an outfile. The ODUDAT and ODUCEN fields contain the last used date.

```
DSPOBJD OBJ(QGPL/*ALL) OBJTYPE(*ALL) OUTPUT(*OUTFILE) OUTFILE(QTEMP/DSPOBJD)
```

then use SQL to view the contents of the outfile:

```
select   a.odlbnm, a.odobnm, a.odobtp, a.odobat,
         a.oducen, a.odudat, a.odcdat, a.odobtx 
from      qtemp/dspobjd a
```

from there you should be able to select on last used date.